# what is diffrence between Control flow diagram & Data flow diagram

Tags: javascript

what is diffrence between Control flow diagram  & Data flow diagram.

Please recoomend which is best for functional specification.

Comment: Not sure about for functional specification, but for code comprehension I have found data flow diagrams are much more useful. I've spent years creating control flow diagrams with limited return on investment.

Comment: -1 please add your effort instead of posting question here directly, a simple google can give you a bunch of important result. :(

Comment: @AlokVishwakarma It's fine to ask questions here too. Though the way it was framed could be better. In this case, the overlap of this term across disciplines makes googling it a bit cumbersome so sometimes context is needed.

Answer (score 1):

**Data flow diagrams** are used to describe data flow within a system. They can depict transformations on data as well as storage locations. They trace the route that data travels in a system, from start to finish.

**Control flow diagrams** are used to describe the detailed logic of a business process or business rule. Control flow diagrams can easily illustrate decisions within the system via decision nodes that branch in different logical paths.

Comment: I like the first paragraph. The 2nd paragraph might sound too vague to newbies, so I'll say a control flow diagram effectively shows you which method calls which other method

Answer (score 0):

CONTROL FLOW diagram is a diagram to describe the flow of of process or programm.
DFD is siginificant modeling techniqeue for analyzing and constructing information process

Answer (score 0):

A data flow model is diagrammatic representation of the flow and exchange of information within a system.

A Control Flow Graph (CFG) is the graphical representation of control flow or computation during the execution of programs or applications.